# Django - Automatically Create Model When Creating User

Tags: python, django, class, model

I have a Student Model, which should extend the Base User Model. Now I did this with a One to One Relation, but once my WebApp is done, I'd like to be able to create all the Users fast. Is there a way of adding all the fields of the Student Model into the User Creating Panel in /admin/? Here is my User Model for anyone wondering:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    street_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0, MaxValueValidator(9999))])

    def return_address(self):
        address = self.street + ' ' + str(self.street_number) + ' ' + self.city + ' ' + str(self.code) + ' ' + self.province
        return address

    def __str__(self):
        address = self.return_address()
        return f'Adresse: {address}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals.

```
# <appname>/signals.py

from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from <model_path> import Student

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_student_after_user_init(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # logic runs after user creation (not update)
        Student._default_manager.create(user=instance)
```

```
# <appname>/apps.py

...

class <AppName>Config(AppConfig):
    ...
    def ready(self):
        # connect signals to the app
        from <appname> import signals
```

```
# <appname>/__init__.py

# State which AppConfig to use
default_app_config = "<appname>.apps.<AppName>Config"
```